# How to test or call a java method using fitnesse?

Tags: java, fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

My requirement is to test or call a java method directly through `fitnesse` tool. I have used this tool for REST testing, but never for calling java methods directly. Also googled , but no solution. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer finally :

To call any method of any Java class, just use `Generic Fixture` 
Eg.

Java class :

```
package com.fitnesse.fixtures;


public class HelloWorld {

    public long getValue()
    {
        return 10;
    }

}
```

Fitnesse script to call the fore-mentioned java class :

```
!| Generic Fixture | com.fitnesse.fixtures.HelloWorld|
|myvar=getValue||10|
```

So first line calls the default constructor of the Java class, and 
second line calls the method getValue and saves it in myvar and also validates it with 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write 'fixture' code which connects FitNesse to your Java classes.

You'll find details here: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide

For example, here's some information on one way to do that: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitLibraryUserGuide.DoFixture

Comment: Thanks for the links, I wrote a fixture : !define TEST_RUNNER (fitlibrary.suite.FitLibraryServer)

!path C:\Fitnesse_1\fitnesse.jar
!path C:\Fitnesse_1\fitlibrary.jar
!path C:\Fitnesse_1\com.jar

!|com.fitnesse.HelloWorldFixture|
|show|say hi|  , but when i m running it , it shows   Error: Could not find or load main class fitlibrary.suite.FitLibraryServer

Comment: Have you imported your fixture in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Using a script table you can do something like this:

For static methods

```
|script   |java.util.UUID.randomUUID|
|$uuidVar=|to string                |
|check    |to string                | $uuidVar |
```

For non static methods

```
|script             | MyClass       |constructor   |arguments|here|
|$classToString=    | to string     |
|check              | to string     |$classToString|
|$classReference=   | get fixture   |
|$storeMethodOutput=| my method name|
```

Any of the $ variables defined can be reference in later tables for just about whatever you need.